# Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.google.android.gms:play-services' not found

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

In one of my projects I need to use `GoogleMaps` and `Firebase` for notifications but the libraries of the service and the Firebase in place do not want to work.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.online.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 8
        versionName "2.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }    
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.6@aar'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
```

Error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.google.android.gms:play-services' not found.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2s 325ms)
```

Comment: Did the above build.gradle is inside app module build.gradle or **root** build.gradle ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
```

to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

check this for more info: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.google.android.gms:play-services' not found.

Comment: i did change --- Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1.

Comment: change this `classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` to this ``classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1``

Comment: changed  --- Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1. --- I have been suffering for a week with this )))

Comment: did not help --- Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1.

Comment: change this `maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }` to this `maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }` remove `/` and remove those: `repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}` in the other file

Comment: without change
Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1.

Comment: I downloaded
google-services-3.1.0.jar and google-services-3.1.0.pom and placed at android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.1.0/ and it all worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1.

Comment: which version of Android studio you are using?

Comment: In you application gradle change   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'  
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' in dependency section of buildscript

Comment: You need to update your Gradle version to 3.1.0 That will probably resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors:

In your `buildscript` block **use the right plugin**:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    // ...
}
```

Instead of `classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

Then at the bottom you have also **to change the name of the plugin**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

instead of:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
```

**Also don't use 2** `buildscript` blocks.

Just remove this block, and add the repository and the plugin in the previous block:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```